# Custom Icons Package : Icons not appear

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

### Problem Description

I am trying to create an icon package in Flutter so I follow the steps here [How to use custom icons in Flutter?](https://medium.com/codechai/how-to-use-custom-icons-in-flutter-834a079d977) The blog doesn't mention the project type ( Application or package ). I create a Package and follow the steps.

[image: flutter project]

### The Icons doesn't appear

I tried to test the package so I created an example (Application) within the package. I call the package in `pubspec.yaml` like this

```yaml
dependencies:
  iconic:
    path: D:\Git-Hub\Android-Studio\Flutter\Iconic
```

[Repo link](https://github.com/moha-b/Iconic)

### Attempts to Solve the Issue

- I doubt that the icons may be causing some issues that [FlutterIcon](https://www.fluttericon.com/) does while converting the icons. To make sure that's not happening I take the `.tff` file and create a new flutter project and it works fine.

### Screenshots or Code Snippets

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    const Icon(
      Iconic.home_bold,  // <- the icon
      size: 60,
    ),
    ...//
  ],
),
```

[image: flutter project]

### Environment

Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Windows 11

Flutter 3.10.0 • channel stable

Dart 3.0.0 • DevTools 2.23.1